# what happened after call std::thread::join()?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm a beginner in multithreads,and there is something I don't understand in cpp standard multithreads library:

```
void func(){
//do something
}
int main(){

std::vector<std::thread> threads;

for(int i=0;i<std::thread::hardware_concurrency();i++)
threads.push_back(func);

for(auto& thread:threads)
thread.join();

//do it again
for(auto& thread:threads)
thread.join();

return 0;
}
```

then comes my problem:when will the third for loop reached?Was it reached after all the thread fihish their job or only need the main thread to finish its job?And if some threads finish the func() earlier than others,how can I let it call the func() even before others threads finish their first call?
Thanks so much for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On doubt, it's always good to check the documentation: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join

> Blocks the current thread until the thread identified by *this finishes its execution.

So, your second loop will wait till all threads in the vector have finished execution. Once all that work has been done, you will only continue to the 3th loop. That loop is basically an expensive noop.

Note: In c++20 they added `std::jthread` to make using threads easier, you now no longer need to think about calling `join()`.